# Can't Boot from Fedora USB

Tags: linux, boot, usb, fedora

I'm trying to boot from a USB with Fedora ISO on it, but it goes straight to windows 10. I've set the boot order to try the USB first and I'm pretty sure that the files are correct on the USB [Files](https://gyazo.com/73c489d468a39b1a0dabb6fcf3d70163). I used [Universal-USB-Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to put the ISO on the USB, I'm trying to install Fedora 23 and my motherboard is Asus Sabertooth z77.

Comment: The Boot Menu key should be F7, what happens when you are tapping F7 while you turn the machine on?

Comment: @MichaelFrank i get into the boot menu and set the usb as the 1st priority to try to boot into

Comment: Is your bios configured for UEFI or legacy mode? If UEFI, the usb flash drives can be tricky to create a boot image on for fedora, and they explicitly state that most 3rd party tools will not work. Some info here: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_Live_USB

Comment: @Argonauts So I don't know if this is what your talking about, but my usb shows up with UEFI ontop of it. I actually got it to load into Fedora by pressing F8 and selecting My USB.

Comment: Your bios is configured for uefi or legacy mode. Check the settings in the bios menu. I'm not sure what you mean by intop of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually an answer because I got it to work by doing this. So, For anyone with an Asus Sabertooth Motherboard, when you turn on your PC spam f2, to get into bios and go to boot menu (f8) and select your device. It should restart instantly and load into Fedora

Answer (score 0):

If USB is set for UEFI make sure your BIOS is set to boot to UEFI. When you select your USB boot device from the boot menu normally it should say UEFI next to it in order for it to work. I've had success setting up a bootable Fedora UEFI device in the past with RUFUS USB on Windows as well as the Gnome Disk Utility.